# Not able to type in Conda Run terminal

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

This question could be odd or due to some naive error, but so far I have not been able to fix this : I am not able to type anything in my Conda run terminal.

I wanted to install Pandas in my Win64/Win10 machine and following online tutorials [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/install.html) and other visible links from google, I learned that installing with Anaconda is easier.

Thus, I installed Anaconda and following the command from this [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pandas) I am trying to run the following command in my Conda terminal

```
    conda install -c conda-forge pandas=0.19.0
```

However, when I open the Conda.exe, the terminal opens but does not accept any input from the keyboard nor mouse. (even when run as admin).

[image]

Can anyone point out what the reason could be?

Comment: A) Once you've installed Anaconda, you have installed Pandas. There's no need for any further command line steps. 
B) If for some reason you do later on need to open the anaconda terminal, note that it should be something like cmd.exe, not conda.exe. I recommend just opening it from the start menu.

Comment: @SohierDane I opened it from start, and it looked similar to cmd.exe . I did install Anaconda. Does that mean Pandas is automatically installed? The links however suggest otherwise.

Comment: It means pandas is installed. The easiest way to validate this is by opening Spyder, the IDE that comes with Anaconda, and running 'import pandas'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon @Sohier's comment, you should run those commands in your "Command Prompt" terminal (i.e. `cmd.exe`). The `conda.exe` program that you are executing is designed to be run from  the command line; it takes parameters.

Try opening your command prompt and then typing `conda list`. You should see a long list of packages including `pandas`. If you don't see it there then you can install it using `conda install pandas`. This will install `pandas` in your root `conda` environment.

Answer (score -1):

You should understand that 'command prompt' and 'anaconda prompt' interface looks alike but not the same thing. For clarity of doubt, when you are in anaconda prompt, it usually begins with (base) while command prompt begins with C: or D: as the case maybe.

On pandas, any time you installed anaconda, some basic packages comes with it. So you don't need to install something like pandas, numpy, etc again.